# File atomicity with luigi python library

Tags: python, pandas, luigi

Do I need to worry about file atomicity in luigi with the following code, picking a dataframe and returning it as an output from a task?  I don't get the atomicity part, as I would hope luigi would just wait for the task to complete writing a file before stating the task is complete.

```
class readSQLtoPickle(luigi.Task):

    sql = luigi.Parameter()
    pickle = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.pickle,format=format.Nop)


    def run(self):
        data = pd.read_sql(self.sql, ariel)
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            pickle.dump(data, f)





class grabData(luigi.Task): # standard Luigi Task class

    sql = luigi.Parameter(default="SELECT * FROM DIM_DRUG_PRODUCT")
    pickle = luigi.Parameter(default="drug_product.pkl")

    def requires(self):
    # we need to read the log file before we can process it
        return readSQLtoPickle(sql=self.sql, pickle=self.pickle)

    def run(self):
        with self.input().open('r') as f:
            df = pickle.load(f)
            print(type(df))
            print(df.head(100))
            print(len(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing to LocalTarget is atomic. Behind the scene lugi first writes to a temp file and then moves the temp file to your actual target. Look for atomic_file [in the source code](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/local_target.py)

> I don't get the atomicity part, as I would hope luigi would just wait for the task to complete writing a file before stating the task is complete.

If you use a local scheduler to run your task (`--local-scheduler`) and have only one worker, then you should be fine.

It becomes a problem if you have several workers working on the same tasks and are trying to identity which tasks are now available to run.

In your example one worker could be trying to check if `grabData` is ready to run, and see that the file is available while another worker is in the middle of `readSQLtoPickle` writing on the file.